# use nested foreach for showing posts and comments in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, nested

how can i use nested foreach for showing posts and comments in laravel ?

this is my Route :

```
Route::get('/showpost', function () {
    $showpost = Posts::all();
    $comment = Comment::all();
    return view('showpost', compact('showpost', 'comment'));
});
```

and here it's my view :

```
            <h1>Posts :</h1>
            @foreach($showpost as $showpost)

                <h1>{{ $showpost->Title }}</h1>
                <h5>{{ $showpost->Content }}</h5>

                {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'showpost','method'=>'post')) }}

                   <h5>{{ Form::label('Comment : ') }} {{ Form::text('Comment') }}</h5>
                    {{ Form::hidden('invisible', $showpost->ID) }}
                    {{ Form::submit('Send Comment') }}

                {{ Form::close() }}

                <hr style='margin-top: 10%'>

            @endforeach

            <hr>
            <h1>Comments :</h1>
            @foreach($comment as $comment)
            {{ $comment->Comment }} -> {{ $comment->PostID }} <br>
            @endforeach
```

Posts show here and a textbox under it show too and we can add comment
i want to show comments about the posts under each posts

now i can't use nested foreach!!!

Comment: did you add the eloquent relationship in your models between your posts and comments?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at this [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/15) series, it will show you how to implement relationships like this.

Comment: before reading the documentation did you add foreignkey into database migration or not?

Answer (score 1):

You should use eloquent [relationship()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships). In your post `model`-

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

And then in your `controller` -

```
$showposts = Posts::with('comments')->get();
return view('showpost')->with('showposts', $showposts);
```

And in your `view`-

```
 <h1>Posts :</h1>
        @foreach($showposts as $showpost)

            <h1>{{ $showpost->Title }}</h1>
            <h5>{{ $showpost->Content }}</h5>

            {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'showpost','method'=>'post')) }}

               <h5>{{ Form::label('Comment : ') }} {{ Form::text('Comment') }}</h5>
                {{ Form::hidden('invisible', $showpost->ID) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Send Comment') }}

            {{ Form::close() }}

            <hr style='margin-top: 10%'>

             <hr>
        <h1>Comments :</h1>
        @foreach($showpost->comments as $comment)
        {{ $comment->Comment }} -> {{ $comment->PostID }} <br>
        @endforeach 

        @endforeach
```

This way you will get `comments` associate with your `posts`.

Comment: where i write relationship ?

Comment: @Mohammad As i said in my answer, write your relationship in your post model. I would suggest first see the laravel docs about relationship and then go further.